# how to set multiple CSS style properties in typescript for an element?

Tags: css, typescript, tslint

Please consider the below snippet. i need to set multiple CSS properties in typescript. for that i have tried the below code.

```
public static setStyleAttribute(element: HTMLElement, attrs: { [key: string]: Object }): void {
        if (attrs !== undefined) {
            Object.keys(attrs).forEach((key: string) => {
                element.style[key] = attrs[key];
            });
        }
    }
```

for the above code i need to pass the parameters as

```
let elem: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('myDiv');
setStyleAttribute(elem, {font-size:'12px', color : 'red' , margin-top: '5px'});
```

But the above code throws error(tslint) as Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
(property) HTMLElement.style: CSSStyleDeclaration.

Please help me !!!

Comment: error thrown in this line   .......... element.style[key]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try using `setAttribute`.  TypeScript does not have the `style` property on `Element`.

```
element.setAttribute("style", "color:red; border: 1px solid blue;");
```

Some related discussion in this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3263

Comment: This code has the side effect, that it kills all old style definitions.

Comment: That's true!  You'd need to use `element.getAttribute('style')` and merge the two together to maintain existing styles.

Answer (score 15):

Just a little late to the party, but anyway...

The actual problem is not that `style` is not defined on `Element`. The word `Element` at the beginning of `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'. (property) HTMLElement.style: CSSStyleDeclaration` is just the first word in a sentence and therefore uppercased. Means it does not relate in any way to the `Element` object - which is quite confusing.

However, the error message means that you are trying to access a property using the subscript operator `[]` with an incorrectly typed index. In your case your `key` is of type `string` but `HTMLElement.style` is a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object which has an index signature of `[index: number]: string` and consequently requires your key to be of type `number`.

The index signature comes from the `typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts` declaration file in your TypeScript installation. There you will find `CSSStyleDeclaration`.

So what you can do is simply cast to `any` like so:

```
(<any>element.style)[key] = attr[key];
```

It's not the best solution but it works and is straightforward. It also does not require you to stringify your styles like it would be necessary when you use `element.setAttribute`.

Comment: BTW: Does anyone know why the `CSSStyleDeclaration` in TypeScript's declarations file has that number-based index signature instead of a string-based? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: It reflects the browser. Try: `myElement.style[0]` to access the first style of myElement.

Comment: Here's the related issue on github https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17827

Answer (score 14):

The API you were searching for is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty

```
public static setStyleAttribute(element: HTMLElement, attrs: { [key: string]: string }): void {
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(attrs)) {
        element.style.setProperty(key, value);
    }
}
```

And hyphen is not allowed in object keys, so use ' here, too:

```
let elem: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('myDiv');
setStyleAttribute(elem, {'font-size':'12px', color: 'red', 'margin-top': '5px'});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. TypeScript's CSSStyleDeclaration has number-based indexing (referenced in comments on other answers here) so string keys don't work. setProperty accepts string keys and has the same effect as `style[key] = val` without resorting to unsafe typing. Thanks @HolgerJeromin

Comment: This answer is useful, but `element.style.setProperty(key, attrs[key]);` will give an error since `attrs[key]` is an Object when the function expects a string.

Comment: Wow. All the years and no one found the wrong type in the function signature! Thanks! I fixed the signature and changed to a for-of loop.

Answer (score 10):

I hope this helps you or someone else...

You can achieve this using a `HTLMDivElement` and the `CSSStyleDeclaration` contained within it. eg.

```
var container: HTMLDivElement;

container.style.color = "red";
container.style.fontSize = "12px";
container.style.marginTop = "5px";
```

This also applies to other classes that inherit from `HTMLElement` and have a `style` property (for example `HTMLBodyElement`.

Comment: may be for some one. not for my scenario..:)

Answer (score 3):

### This problem was post in 06 Jun 2016，Typescript 2.1RC was release in 09 Nov 2016 that had new feature to solve the problem

After reading [Typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and [declaration for dom style](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b45cf0d694401aeec9023f731e5da7ad8e418f71/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L2713), I had found the key of this problem that missing string index signature in Typescript declaration for dom style like following code:

```
interface CSSStyleDeclaration {
  accentColor: string;
  alignContent: string;
  // ....
  [index: number]: string;
}
```

It should be like this (so we can resolve the problem):

```
interface CSSStyleDeclaration {
  accentColor?: string;
  alignContent?: string;
  // ....
  [index: number]: string;
  [propName: string]: string;
}
```

I had used Utility Types to create a new Type for style and it worked:

```
type styleDeclaration = Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> & { [propName: string]: string };
```

If you wanna learn more about this, you can take a look at this [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=87&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAzqA2EAiEDG8CGAnDwCWA9gHZQC8UACtvhvADwDCAyiwsmpjvsQHxQBkUAN5QA2mCwEwAOQwBbCAC5YwLHiIBzALrK4azVAC+AbgBQqYnCgATAnLI2CqAK4KiwAHSosEXBACiiG7AABQA5NZ4AG5hAJRmFkRWcCCIAPIARgBWumwo6Ni4hCTkIgDueNbAABbKYQCMAAyNYAAeYQA0UNUQeBrVwHUATM1tYUZmmVlongDWECAwISnp2bEeAGYEWP4YqNUhy2wA0gu5+hqxZHxCplBQIbZyHivQGDAqqewFXMWxoq9TiAtA5XlMAScFlozIZYuZLAREB54AQNI87C82B4KlVqvEgA).

```
type styleDeclaration = Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> & { [propName: string]: string };

const dom = document.createElement('div');

const styleObj: styleDeclaration = { width: '100px', height: '200px' };

Object.keys(styleObj).forEach((styleKey: string) => {
  (dom.style as styleDeclaration)[styleKey] = styleObj[styleKey];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this for a single element, and iterate over it to make it dynamic

```
let el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('elementID');

el.style.height = "500px";
```

Comment: I've used this with TypeScript / Angular. Normally, `document.getElementById()` can return as an `Element` type, make sure you use `let el: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('elementID');` to change it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An unsafe / untyped way:

```
const e = document.createElement("div")
Object.assign(e.style, {borderSize: "1rem", verticalAlign: "middle"})
```

You'll need to convert standard CSS style naming to the TypeScript alternatives for this to work. i.e. `font-size` vs. `fontSize`. Be warned: You will get no errors on a bad style name. `{attrFOO: "bar"}` is valid.