# TS 2540: Cannot assign to style because it is a read-only property

Tags: typescript

I am creating a `textarea` element in my TSX markup, and the [TS typechecker in Vim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) complains `2540: Cannot assign to style because it is a read-only property`. Having textarea.style be read-only is a bit weird, given that it can be written to ...

[image: vim error]
How can I make the error message disappear? Should I cast the `input` variable in my code to something else?

Comment: I did not know that this was even valid. I only ever assigned the properties within the style map. So here that could be done using e.g. `Object.assign(input.style, { whiteSpace: 'pre', position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px' })`

Comment: @H.B. Sure, that is one way. Kind of common, though. Apparently using a string is not _recommended_ (according to MDN): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style

Answer (score 27):

I solved it by using:

```
input.setAttribute('style', 'white-space: pre; position: absolute; left: -9999px;');
```

Apparently "TypeScript does not have a style property on Element." as was mentioned in a [related Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147914/11715057).

Answer (score 6):

alternatively you can use **input.style.cssText**

`input.style.cssText = "white-space:pre; position:absolute; left:-9999px;";`

Comment: This worked for me, whereas if I tried to cast to `HTMLDivElement` TypeScript still complained about `style` being read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I already had the answer ...

Saying the input variable is the specific type made it work.

```
const input: HTMLTextAreaElement = document.createElement('textarea')                                                                                                   
const currentTarget = e.currentTarget as HTMLDivElement
```

This is probably because `createElement` [can create all kinds of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and Typescript has no way of knowing which, as it is based on the input string. So you need to say what it is returning.

Comment: Actually, the TypeScript type declarations (here `lib.dom.d.ts`) have overloads, so `createElement` should already return the correct type. Where this is not quite possible is `querySelector`, which is not necessarily just a tag name. (So `document.querySelector('a')` gives you type `HTMLAnchorElement` but `document.querySelector('a[href]')` only gives you `Element`.) The problem here is `currentTarget`, which cannot be typed automatically.

Comment: > The problem here is currentTarget, which cannot be typed automatically.
Sure, it is a problem, but that has nothing to do with the error in question. The implicit type for `input` cannot have been correct, as specifying the type made the TS2540 error go away. If TS thought it was a `HTMLTextAreaElement ` already, specifying it would be a no-op.

Comment: That is what i am saying, [it absolutely is a no-op](https://imgur.com/x7ysWgq).

Comment: Also, assigning a string to `style` should always give you an error because the property is typed as read-only. So the only way you should be able to not get the error is if you somehow lose the type information, e.g. assert `any`.

Comment: @H.B. The TS compiler never complained, but the linter somehow did, and to it, adding the type was not a no-op, ... No idea what the difference is caused by.

Answer (score 0):

how variant:

```
input.style.whiteSpace = 'pre';
input.style.position = 'absolute';
input.style.left = '-9999px';
```

Answer (score 0):

`style` property is immutable, use `setProperty` method

`element.style.setProperty(propName, propValue)`

so in your case for example: `input.style.setProperty("height", "10px")`

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty