# Picking up an ID from html to typescript- with colors

Tags: html, typescript, colors, element

I have an html-document and a typescript-document, they are linked together.

in index.html

```html
    <p id="miniTag" class="red">This is my paragraph</p>
```

in main.ts

```
document.getElementById("miniTag") as HTMLElement;
```

My question is--> how do I make the p-tag/ID red through typescript?

I have tried this

in main.ts

```
document.getElementById("miniTagg") as HTMLElement{
color: red;
}
```

but I get wrong message because of {} ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set multiple CSS style properties in typescript for an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655393/how-to-set-multiple-css-style-properties-in-typescript-for-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

This will set the "color" css property to "red":

```
document.getElementById("miniTagg").style.color = "red"
```

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) gives more information about how to modify the style of an element using javascript.